# Authorize.net and Automatic Recurring Billing (ARB)

Tags: pledges, authorize.net

We have authorize.net running for over 2 years, Added Automated Recurring Billing. It worked for a test, when we tried to use it for a real event it failed. Civicrm shows it working correctly but Authorize.net sees the initial transaction but does not see the ARB transaction.

Comment: While you seem to be asking about a chance in your systems (adding ARB), the timing of your question makes me wonder if you've been affected by [SSL changes on api.authorize.net](http://app.payment.authorize.net/e/es.aspx?s=986383348&e=949852&elq=6d50ae28150246fc9892054a5c7a7981). I would recommend reviewing that technical notice before debugging further.

Comment: In addition to Chris' comments, I assume you checked to ensure the Silent Post URL is set up correctly in your Authorize settings?  Do you see anything in the Civi log indicating that the Authorize script at least tried to match something up?

Comment: We setup silent post, but it is only involved after the ARB  confirms a transaction. is recieved by Authorize.net.  The SSL changes should have impacted all users. They receive out normal request. The SSL is provided by Civicrm, I don't know how to even check if it is correct.